# Do we need to prefix member arguments of nested type with "::"?

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

For instance, consider the following where there is a clash of name `nest1`:

```
template <typename U> class nest1 {};

class cls {
public:
    template <typename V> class nest1 {};

    template <typename W> class nest2 {
    public:
        void bar(nest1<W> x);
    };
};

template <typename W>
void cls::nest2<W>::bar(nest1<W> x) {}  // how does compiler know which nest<1>?
```

- How does the compiler know whether `bar` takes `nest1<W>` or `cls::nest1<W>` if we don't prefix it with `cls::` (e.g. `bar(cls::nest1<W> x)`)?
- Is it good practice to explicitly prefix `cls::` anyhow?

*NB: the compiler actually chooses implicitly to declare* `bar(cls::nest1<W> x)`:

- Calling `cls::nest1<W> x; bar(x);` works: http://ideone.com/3ZuH2Z
- Passing `nest1<W> x; bar(x);` fails: http://ideone.com/6HmA3f

Comment: Same as when you have a global variable and a static data member with the same name.

Comment: So it just peels back the layers and finds the required declaration in the closest parent/ancestor class?

Comment: Oh, I assumed it would choose the global one. You should probably specify that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every name used after the member function name is also looked up inside the lexical scope of its class. This leads to the following (seemingly) inconsistent behaviour, since the normal return type is *not* inside the lexical scope of the class:

```
struct X{
  struct Y{};

  Y foo(Y);
  Y bar(Y);
};

// normal return type is before 'foo', needs explicit scope qualification
// parameter doesn't (after 'foo')
X::Y X::foo(Y y){ return y; }

// trailing-return-type also doesn't (after 'bar')
auto X::bar(Y y) -> Y{ return y; }
```

For the standardese for this, we look at `§9.3 [class.mfct] p5`:

> If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class name using the `::` operator. [ *Note:* **A name used in a member function definition** (that is, in the *parameter-declaration-clause* including the default arguments (8.3.6) or in the member function body) **is looked up as described in 3.4.** *—end note* ] [...]

And then at `§3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual] p8` (unqualified name lookup, e.g. without `::`):

> A name used in the definition of a member function (9.3) of class `X` **following the function’s *declarator-id***<sup>31</sup> [...] shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> - [...]
> - shall be a member of class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2), or
> - [...]

(The *declarator-ids* in my example are `foo` and `bar`.)